# read from text file and put into struct

Tags: c, struct

i have assembler file actually text file like that

```
1         # Test case 1 for assembler
2                 
3                   .text
4    test1:          lwa   $1,val1
5                    prh   $1
6    val12:          lwa   $2,val2
7                    prh   $2
         ..................
```

i am reading each line with fgets and keeping in char buffer which name is "linebuffer"
and im reading linebuffer with sscanf.

```
while((fgets(linebuffer,sizeof(linebuffer),ifp)!=NULL)
{
sscanf(linebuffer,"%s%s%s%s",line[i].label,line[i].opcode,line[i].operands,line[i].comment);
......
}
```

and i want keep them into struct,

```
struct instrucion{
char lable[8];
char opcode[4];
char opearand[15];
char comment[100];
}line[65536];
```

problem is some columns doesnt have anything just space and sscanf skipping spaces and reading very next string and keeping in first column. sorry i could not understand exactly but i hope somebody is understand.

for example i want like that for 3rd line;

```
line[2].label=NULL
line[2].opcode=".text"
line[2].opernds=NULL
line[2].comment=NULL
```

for 4th line;

```
line[3].label="test1:"
line[3].opcode="lwa"
line[3].operands="$1,val1"
line[3].comment=NULL
```

problem is starting with 5th line its has to be like that

```
line[4].label=NULL
line[4].opcode="prh"
line[4].operands="$1"
line[4].comment=NULL
```

buts when i run code im getting this result;

```
line[4].label="prh"
line[4].opcode="$1"
line[4].opernds=NULL
line[4].comment=NULL
```

how can i deliminate this linebuffer correctly?

Comment: `%s` means read the whole line till you encounter `\0` or `\n`(`\r\n` in windows).

Comment: i know but i think i have to read this linebuffer with something else

Comment: no reading the line is ok but sscanf() will be useless to read a substring from a string. your own funtion to tokenize will be good idea. internally your function could use strtok();

Comment: are there equal spaces between all the different parts of the single line? e.g in the line containing `.text` is`.text` guarenteed to have a particular offset space from the starting of the line?

Comment: no space, tab or multiple spaces

Comment: i thought before strtok but its same thing.

Comment: no what i asked is,for eg, between `test1:` and `lwa   $1,val1` will there be space and if spaces are there will it be constant?

Comment: you cant use strtok directly. use it in your custom function. i wiull tell you this detail once you answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your first problem is that fgets() does not read one line - It reads up to sizeof(linebuffer) number of bytes, you can see it's man page here:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets

Second, say that you do have only one line in the string "linebuffer", what you would like to do is use sscanf return value to determine which tokens appear in the line (scanf functions family return the number of parameters that were read from the stream).

Third, pay attention to the fact the scanf considers only spaces and newlines as tokens separators, so it will not separate the string "$1,val1" to the two sub-strings - you will need to do it manually.

And finally, there's a string-parsing function that can maybe make you life easier- strtok_r. You can see it's man page here:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r

Amnon.

Comment: fgets() does not have to read all the lines at once. if it ecounter `\n` it will stop reading there. since every line will have a newline character(i assume), its still ok